# Trying to output a song where it is made by two artists in sql

Tags: sql, select, phpmyadmin, where-clause

I want to get the song id where I have both the artists. This is what the table looks like

| SONG ID | ARTIST ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2000. | 5000 |
| 2001. | 5001 |
| 2002. | 5000 |
| 2002. | 5001 |

This is my code so far

```
SELECT SONG_ID 
FROM SONG_ARTIST
WHERE ARTIST_ID = '5000' and '5001'
```

This gives me two songs when I only want the one output which is 2002 but it gives me 2001 and 2002 as the output. I know its something to do in the where clause but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - the issue is with your where clause.

Current code:

```
SELECT SONG_ID 
FROM SONG_ARTIST 
WHERE   ARTIST_ID = '5000' 
    and '5001'
```

You never specify the '5001' (like `ARTIST_ID = '5001'` instead of just `'5001'`; however, this won't solve the issue. Each row of data can only have one `ARTIST_ID`; for example, the first row has

| SONG_ID | ARTIST_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5000 |

Which is only one ARIST_ID. If your where clause is `ARTIST_ID = '5000' and ARTIST_ID = '5001'`, you won't get the data back because the ARTIST_ID can only ever be one entry.

Based on your comment, each row of data is only one song ID and one Artist ID. So assuming your data is like so:

| SONG_ID | ARTIST_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5000 |
| 2001 | 5001 |
| 2002 | 5000 |
| 2002 | 5001 |

One option you could do is subquery to split the data into two tables, then find the matching pairs. For example:

```
With artist5000 as {
Select Distinct SONG_ID from SONG_ARTIST
Where ARTIST_ID = '5000'
},
artist5001 as {
Select Distinct SONG_ID from SONG_ARTIST
Where ARTIST_ID = '5001'
}

Select *
From artist5000
where Song_ID in (Select * from artist5001);
```

You could also play around with the output a little if you like. For example, if you want the data to look like this:

| SONG_ID | ARTIST_IDs |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5000,5001 |

You could change the last query to:

```
Select *, '5000,5001' as ARTIST_IDs
From artist5000
where Song_ID in (Select * from artist5001);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up makes a lot more sense!! :)